# Why `lambda: MyClass()` is legal but `MyClass()` itself is illegal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, oop, trie

**The following code are legal:**

```
class MyClass:
    print(lambda: MyClass())
```

```
class MyClass:
    print(lambda: self())
```

```
class MyClass:
    children = defaultdict(lambda: MyClass())

mc = MyClass()
print(mc.children)
cc = mc.children[0]
print(cc.children)
```

**However, the following code are illegal:**

```
class MyClass:
    def f(): return MyClass()
    print(f()) #=> NameError: name 'MyClass' is not defined
```

```
class MyClass:
    children = MyClass() #=> NameError: name 'MyClass' is not defined
```

```
class MyClass:
    children = self() #=> NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

**My question is, why do `MyClass` and `self` become `defined` once wrapped in lambda?**

(I was playing with Trie structure and trying to understand why TrieNode is necessarily defined as a separate class. TrieNode is basically a one line class defined with `children = defaultdict(lambda: TrieNode())`)

Comment: You didn't *call* the lambda.

Comment: It's like `print(f)`, not `print(f())`.

Comment: The function body (here: the expression returned by the lambda function) is only evaluated when the function is called. If you call it *before* the class is defined, it will raise an error.

Comment: Hi @user2357112supportsMonica, @ schwobaseggl, thank you!  so ... those are not fair comparison that I gave. Then I added a third legal example in my post just now, is that counted as `calling the lambda function`? Thanks again!

Comment: The third example does call the function, but only after the class definition is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The factory function passed to the `defaultdict` in:

```
class TrieNode:
    children = defaultdict(lambda: TrieNode())
```

is not called during the class definition. Once the class is defined, the function has access to the class name from the enclosing namespace. The following will fail with a similar error you encountered:

```
class TrieNode:
    children = defaultdict(lambda: TrieNode())
    children[4]  # calls factory function before class is defined!


NameError: name 'TrieNode' is not defined
```

An even more dramatic example for illustrating the enclosing namespace fact:

```
class TrieNode:
    children = defaultdict(lambda: TrieNode())

t = TrieNode()

TrieNode = int

t.children[5]
# 0  
# [sic!] ...
# ... t is still a TrieNode from the earlier class definiton, 
# but the factory function uses the latter override from the enclosing namespace
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize namespace is a thing, reading on it now.